# .Net c# WebRequest Post

Tags: c#, webrequest

Pessoal estou estudando WebRequest, estou tentando fazer uma consulta no site dos correios e pelo que li deveria ficar assim:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/resultado.cfm");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("objetos=PU633524761BR");
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        textBox.Text = responseFromServer;
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
```

porém ao ser executado não esta aparecendo o histórico de postagem do objeto para que eu possa recuperar a informação

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que não é assim que consome a API de rastreio dos correios. Você já leu a documentação da mesma?

Comment: sim, não é mesmo, eu apenas estou estudando a questão de WebRequest, para consumir a API dos correios é totalmente diferente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que você tenha se confundido com a ordem das requisições feitas pela página e por isso não a está emulando corretamente. Analisando percebi que ela faz primeiro uma requisição em outra página e então redireciona para a qual você está tentando fazer a chamada (o que não vai dar certo porque como vem por cookies você não vai ter nada). O correto é mais ou menos assim:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/ctrl/ctrlRastreamento.cfm?");  //alterado para o lugar correto do post, fiz um cast pra httpwebrequest para poder usar o cookiecontainer e assim tê-los na próxima página.
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
            var cookies = new CookieContainer();  //incluido cookie container
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;  //atribuido a requisição
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("objetos=PU633524761BR");
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
```

Comment: na verdade o que estava errado era o HTTPS e nao HTTP